# Print an array of hashes ordered by a hash key

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes like this

```
{'id' => 'ID001', 'count' => 1}
{'id' => 'ID003', 'count' => 2}
{'id' => 'ID002', 'count' => 1}
```

I do this to print the list

```
myarray.each_with_index do |i, p|
    puts "\n #{p+1}) #{i['id']} n. #{i['count'].to_s}"
end
```

It works perfectly, in fact, I obtain this:

```
1) 'ID001' n. 1
2) 'ID003' n. 2
3) 'ID002' n. 1
```

Is it possible to order the hashes by `"ID"` key?

Comment: `myarray.sort_by { |h| h['id'] }`

Comment: @iGian not that simple: `myarray.sort_by { |h| h['id'][/\d+/].to_i }`

Comment: @mudasobwa is it because you care about this situation `'ID3000'`, `'ID301'`?

Comment: @iGian exactly.

Comment: If you wish to sort on the value of `'ID'` you need to tell us (with an edit) if the value of `'ID'` is always of length `5` and always begins with `'ID'`.

Comment: No the value doesn't start always by ID, but length is always 5. For my need the code poste by mudasobwa it's enough

Comment: That’s fine as long as you know that mudsie’s code will cause `”ID001”` to preceed `”AA002”` in the sort. Btw, I just happened to see your last comment days after you posted it. For me to be notified by SO of your comment you need to include my username in the comment. See comments above for examples.

Comment: @CarySwoveland i usually do it.... I forgot to add your name, sorry! But thank's  for your interest. Tell me, How would you solve my problem? Another opinion is always appreciable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myarray.
  sort_by { |h| h['id'][/\d+/].to_i }.
  each.
  with_index(1) do |h, idx|
    puts ["\n", "#{idx})", h['id'], "n.", h['count']].join(' ')
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can yoi explain `|h| h['id'][/\d+/].to_i` to me? I don't find an explanation online...

Comment: You probably want it to be ordered by numerical value, e.g. `ID10` should come after `ID9`. Alphabetical sorting would place `ID10` first, so I filter out digits only and convert it to integer to make it to compare `10` and `9` instead.

Answer (score 0):

my_array looks like this:

```
{"ID02"=>"xx", "ID01"=>"a", "ID00"=>"ba", "ID04"=>"zz"}
```

when you run this:

```
my_array.sort_by { |key, value| key }
```

output would return an array as:

```
[["ID00", "ba"], ["ID01", "a"], ["ID02", "xx"], ["ID04", "zz"]]
```

I guess you still want it to be in a Hash, but it isn't a Hash's inherent functionality to have ordered keys.